# Jquery getting an attribute from a list

Tags: jquery, list

I have the following code

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a><img src="mysource" alt="my alt tag 1"/></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a><img src="mysource" alt="my alt tag 2"/></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a><img src="mysource" alt="my alt tag 3"/></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a><img src="mysource" alt="my alt tag 4"/></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to get the alt tag of the image. I have the position of the list item i'm trying to access saved in a variable 'currentPos' but I can't get the alt content. Any help would be great. This is what i've tried so far

```
altText = $("ul li").index(currentPos).find('img').attr('alt');
```

Comment: Maybe this will work: $("ul li['+currentPos+'] img").attr('alt')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
var altText = $("ul li").eq(currentPos).find('img').attr('alt');
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aHbNQ/).

`index` returns a number indicating the index position of the element, whereas `eq` actually gets the element at the specified index.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
altText = $("ul li").eq(currentPos).find('img').attr('alt');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
altText = $('ul li').eq(currentPos).find('img').attr('alt');
```

Where currentPos is a 0 based index. so the first item is 0